# MutationObserver callback keeps firing

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to have a MutationObserver watch for changes to a page title and immediately reset the title back to the original text. This partially works, but the first time the page title is changed,  my callback keeps firing and the page grinds to a halt. I've tried disconnecting the observer in my callback, and that stops it from looping, but I actually need it to keep observing, so it isn't a solution.

What am I doing wrong?

```
function resetTitle(title) {
    document.title = title[0].oldValue;
    console.info("Reset the page title.");
}

let observer = new MutationObserver(resetTitle);

observer.observe(document.querySelector('title'), {
  childList: true,
  subtree: true,
  characterDataOldValue: true
});
```

Comment: you should add a triggering conditions of the resetTitle

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is how you want to do that (updated based on Kaiido's correction below)(and removed the title parameter since we don't use it).

```
var originalTitle = document.title;
    
    function resetTitle() {
        if( originalTitle != document.title ){    
        // disable the observer while you make the change
                observer.disconnect();
                document.title = originalTitle;
                console.info("Reset the page title.");
        
                // now enable it again
                observer.observe(document.querySelector('title'), {
                childList: true,
                subtree: true,
                characterDataOldValue: true
                });
            }
        
    }
    
    let observer = new MutationObserver(resetTitle);
    
    observer.observe(document.querySelector('title'), {
      childList: true,
      subtree: true,
      characterDataOldValue: true
    });
```

Comment: This is great. I hadn't realized I had set up a feedback loop, but all answers so far have identified it. D'oh. Marking this as the correct answer because it's the most succinct and similar to my original code. Thank you!

Comment: @lshillman this answer will fail to grab the correct `oldValue`. Using this, if the first modification of the document's title isn't done through `document.querySelector("title").firstChild.data = newValue` (i.e. in most cases), you will reset the document's title to the empty string, because `oldValue` will be `null`.

Comment: @Kaiido Oh, interesting. I hadn't realized that the method you use to change the value would actually matter. So you need to store the original title from the beginning, and use that instead of the oldValue passed by the observer?

Comment: Basically, yes, that's the simplest and most bullet proof solution + it doesn't change anything since the one you conceptually wanted was the current-value at the time you began your observer.

Comment: @Kaiido makes sense. Thank you so much. I haven't messed with MutationObserver before; very grateful for your help.

Comment: @Kaiido - Thank you!  I see that you are correct (have tested this using originalValue now), but I don't understand why you used setTimeout in your solution.  I rewrote mine to save and use the originalTitle and it seems good now.  Can you explain?

Comment: As said in the earlier snippets I use setTimeout only for the StackSnippet to already have a `<title>` in its document. Failing to do so, the original title would be `""`since there is no `<title>` being set by StackSnippet.

Comment: @ChadPhillips I suppose, now that we're storing the original title, we don't need to pass characterDataOldValue to the callback anymore.

Comment: It's true - we don't use it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

First, when the `document.title` [is set](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#document.title), the [string replace all](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#string-replace-all) algorithm is used, which will replace all the previous content of the `<title>` element with a new `TextNode`.
Doing so, there is no `CharacterData` mutation occurring, only a `childList` one, which will not fill the `previousValue` field.

```js
document.title = "original title";
// StackSnippets don't set a title, so we need to wait after we set the initial
// title before starting our observer
setTimeout(() => {
  function resetTitle(title) {
      console.log("oldValue:", title[0].oldValue);
      console.log("type:", title[0].type);
  }

  let observer = new MutationObserver(resetTitle);

  observer.observe(document.querySelector('title'), {
    childList: true,
    subtree: true,
    characterDataOldValue: true
  });
  document.title = Math.random();
}, 100)
```

You could have used that if the title was set by modifying the existing `TextNode` directly:

```js
document.title = "original title";
// StackSnippets don't set a title, so we need to wait after we set the initial
// title before starting our observer
setTimeout(() => {
  function resetTitle([record]) {
    console.log("oldValue:", record.oldValue);
  }

  let observer = new MutationObserver(resetTitle);
  observer.observe(document.querySelector('title'), {
    subtree: true,
    characterDataOldValue: true,
  });

  document.querySelector('title').firstChild.data = Math.random();
}, 100);
```

So what you need is actually to handle both the possible `CharacterData` mutation, and the `childList` one, by looking at the `removedNodes[0].data` to get the old value.
But if you're going to modify the title again in your handler, you will trigger once more the observer's callback, with this time, the *new* title being set as the old one.
So instead, the best is to store the original value that you want to keep from outside of the observer's callback, and to check in the callback if the title needs an update or not:

```js
// Store the original title when you start the observer
const originalTitle = document.title;
function resetTitle([record]) {
  // Only if needed, even setting to the same value would trigger a childList change.
  if (document.title !== originalTitle) {
    document.title = originalTitle;
    console.log("resetting title");
  }
}
let observer = new MutationObserver(resetTitle);
observer.observe(document.querySelector('title'), {
  childList: true,
  subtree: true,
  characterDataOldValue: true,
});
```

```js
document.title = "original title";
// Below setTimeout is for this demo only,
// StackSnippets don't set a <title>, so we need to wait after we set the initial
// title before starting our observer
setTimeout(() => {
  // Store the original title when you start the observer
  const originalTitle = document.title;
  function resetTitle([record]) {
    // Only if needed, even setting to the same value would trigger a childList change.
    if (document.title !== originalTitle) {
      document.title = originalTitle;
      console.log("resetting title");
    }
  }
  let observer = new MutationObserver(resetTitle);
  observer.observe(document.querySelector('title'), {
    childList: true,
    subtree: true,
    characterDataOldValue: true,
  });
  document.querySelector('button.title').onclick = e =>
    document.title = Math.random();
  document.querySelector('button.data').onclick = e =>
    document.querySelector('title').firstChild.data = Math.random();
}, 100);
```

```html
<button class=title>change through `document.title`</button>
<button class=data>change through `TextNode.data`</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have created a feedback loop.  A simple way to avoid the feedback loop, without having to micromanage the subscription, is to simply compare the change to the current value.

You might also want to cache your original title

```js
const originalTitle = document.title;

function resetTitle(newTitle) {
    // Avoid loop by ignoring self change.
    if (originalTitle === newTitle) {
      return    
    }
    document.title = originalTitle;
    console.info("Reset the page title.");
}
```

As another approach, just ignore the event contents and check the title against the cached.  This will also avoid the feedback.

```js
const originalTitle = document.title;

function resetTitle(_title) {
    // Avoid loop by ignoring self change.
    if (document.title !== originalTitle) {
      document.title = originalTitle;
      console.info("Reset the page title.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you see `newValue` was a thing? The only working solution here (the second one) is basically the one already outlined in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77836411/3702797).

Comment: Ahh, it's been a long day. Can't believe I didn't see the loop. Thanks!